# How to use included models with plugins (ROS Hydro and stand alone Gazebo)

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi!,

I am creating my own Gazebo-ROS Package using *SDF* specifications for a ***pioneer2dx*** model including the ***camera*** and ***hokuyo*** models.

For moving the *pioneer2dx* (with *camera* and *hokuyo* included but without their plugins) I used the *gazebo_ros_diff_drive.cpp* plugin from */gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins*. This was tested with a *publisher* to deal with the */cmd_vel* topic. Until there everything is good working and displaying the debug information in a normal way by the *rostopic list* in the terminal.

Now, my problem is when I try to implement the *camera* and the *hokuyo* models included in the *pioneer2dx* model with their respective plugins of */gazebo_ros_pkgs/gazebo_plugins*, *gazebo_ros_camera.cpp* and *gazebo_ros_laser.cpp* which should be filled by the experience of each one because some of their sections are blank (my next step). This is mentioned in Tutorial [ROS_Motor_and_Sensor_Plugins](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/ROS_Motor_and_Sensor_Plugins).

So, I would like to be sure of including the plugins correctly before writing them.

I got some ideas from this [answer](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/2764/passing-parameters-to-included-sdf/) considering there the example of the *dr_vehicle* ([model.config](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/611fc562e081a51723a2a0038a1ad4842b87c643/gazebo_models/environments/drc_vehicle/model.config?at=default) and [model.sdf](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/611fc562e081a51723a2a0038a1ad4842b87c643/gazebo_models/environments/drc_vehicle/model.sdf)) and also following the [latest SDF specification](http://gazebosim.org/sdf/dev.html), but there is still an error on my model.

In the [Tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Tutorials/1.9/Using_roslaunch_Files_to_Spawn_Models), there is a robot's model and description hierarchy explained without plugins implementation in a *SDF* model. I am following this hierarchy of *MYROBOT_description* and *MYROBOT_gazebo* and it works correctly while not including camera and hokuyo plugins.

Should I create each model separatly within the */pioneer_description* file with their respective plugins? so:

/pioneer_description/models/pioneer2dx

/pioneer_description/models/camera

/pioneer_description/models/hokuyo

each one with a plugins file and this also means changes for my .world file located in */pioneer_gazebo*. And also setting the paths as mentioned in this [answer.](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1940/problem-with-including-a-model/)

Does anyone have some recommendations, examples or information about *using included models with plugins* and maybe some experience with the *camera and hokuyo plugins* mentioned above for ROS Hydro and stand alone Gazebo?

Thanks!,

Juan-Diego

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/4246/how-to-use-included-models-with-plugins-(ros-hydro-and-stand-alone-gazebo)/) by [JuDiNiSi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/467/judinisi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-08-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi Juan,

I think there is no "correct" way to do this. For myself I like to separate my robot parts into different files, which are included in a central masterfile. This way, I am able to enable/disable robot parts very quickly. If you choose to put the different parts into different subfolders or not depends on your own taste.

Further more, I used the mesh files that come with gazebo to visualize my sensor (e.g. model://hokuyo/meshes/hokuyo.dae), but since I wanted to use ROS messages, I needed to modify the used plugin "libRayPlugin.so" to "libgazebo_ros_laser.so" anyways, and therefore I wrote my own version of the hokuyo laser scan.

Since I dont use Hydro and standalone gazebo, but groovy and gazebo 1.5, i cant provide any SDF code, because I coded in URDF.

Regards

psei

---

Originally posted by [psei](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/464/psei/) with karma: 166 on 2013-09-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JuDiNiSi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/467/judinisi/) on 2013-09-13**:
Hi! Psei, thank you for your answer! I think so as well. In any case, I also had to do it separately. In the pioneer2dx model.sdf , I included the links for a camera and a hokuyo laser with their ROS plugins given by the gazebo_ros_pkgs for connecting ROS (in catkin_ws) with the new version of Gazebo. I have my own gazebo models file too which was referenced to the corresponding gazebo models path (GAZEBO_MODEL_PATH) as it is explained in some links that I have above in my question.

**Comment by [JuDiNiSi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/467/judinisi/) on 2013-09-13**:
The plugins path are also referenced to the corresponding gazebo plugins path (GAZEBO_PLUGIN_PATH).